# How to send bootstrap design email using laravel

Tags: php, html, email, gmail, laravel-5.6

When I am sending mail to users it shows HTML tags and not the design which I made. Any idea how to show the designs and not the HTML tags. Thank you.

This is my mail template(mail.blade.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head type="text/html">
  <title>Hello User</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .test{
        color:blue;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body type="text/html">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
          <strong><font class="test">Congratulations!</font></strong> You are now a memeber of our team.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my Controller(MailController.php):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
//use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
//use App\SaveMsgModel;
//use Session;
//use DB;
//use Hash;
//use Carbon\Carbon;
//use Validator;
use Mail;

class MailController extends Controller{  
  public function sendmail(){
    Mail::send(['text'=>'mail'],['name'=>'Sam'],function($message){
      $message->to('abcdefg936@gmail.com', 'To raj')->subject('testing laravel mail');
      $message->from('abcdefg936@gmail.com','Mr. Raj');      
    });

    if (Mail::failures()) {
         $x = "Unable to send mail.";
         return $x;
    }    
    $x = "mail send. thank you";
    return $x;
  }
}
```

This is my Route(web.php):

```
   Route::get('/' ,'MailController@sendmail');

   Route::get('mail', 'MailController@sendmail');
```

[image]

Comment: How are you sending those?

Comment: How are you setting the email body?

Comment: You can't add jquery and stuff to HTML emails. Don't use any external resources (except images). When building HTML emails, you should code like it's 1997. Many mail clients won't shlw the emails correctly otherwise.